# Array string to find into sql database, php

Tags: php, arrays

I try the way to find string in sql database. I thing if i have string "a b c d e", for accuracy result, i try "select...from...where column = 'a b c d e' or column='a b c d' or column='a b c' or..." , i try to find the way to get array for implode like this:

```
[0]=>a b c d e,
[1]=>a b c d,
[2]=>a b c,
...
[n]=>a
Can i do
```

like that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: --What have you tried?

Comment: For search on sql database, i explode string before and implode after but how can i get array like that to implode it to sql query.

Comment: I think you'd have to construct the array by yourself. iterate how much array you'd want then implode the strings accordingly.

Comment: i don't know how much array to search result accuracy, i try all array like this (a b c d) or (a b c) or ...

Comment: why? are you sure you don't just need an array of the words? Your array seems kinda redundant to me...  [`Hello`,`everybody`,`nice`,`to`,`meet`,`you`]

Comment: If you are using Mysql. You can do it with regular expressions using `RLIKE`. Build the expression according to your needs [click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Thanks all, i find out the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tokenize the string with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split), build the array and then reverse it with [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/array_reverse):

```
$string = 'foo bar baz';
$results = array(); $current = '';
foreach (preg_split('/ +/', $string) as $token) {
    $current = strlen($current) ? "$current $token" : $token;
    $results[] = $current;
}

print_r(array_reverse($results));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo bar baz
    [1] => foo bar
    [2] => foo
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I find the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd do this, but this will do it:

```
  $string = "Hello everybody, nice to meet you";
  $parts = explode(" ", $string);
  $new_array = Array();

  for($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++)
  {
      $new_array[$i] = '';
      for($j = 0; $j < count($parts) - $i; $j++)
      {
          $new_array[$i] = $new_array[$i]." ".$parts[$j];
      }
  }

  print_r($new_array);
```

Here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  Hello everybody, nice to meet you
    [1] =>  Hello everybody, nice to meet
    [2] =>  Hello everybody, nice to
    [3] =>  Hello everybody, nice
    [4] =>  Hello everybody,
    [5] =>  Hello
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

   $string = "Hello everybody, nice to meet you";

   //remove the comma
   $string = str_replace(',', '', $string);

   //explode for each words with ' '(space) delimiter
   $path = explode(' ', $string);
   $final = array();

   array_push($final, implode(' ', $path));

   foreach($path as $el){
       //remove max array element
       $last_el = count($path) - 1;
       unset($path[$last_el]);

       //set the final array one by one.
       array_push($final, implode(' ', $path));
   }

   //Show the result.
   foreach($final as $row){
       echo $row . ' <br />';
   }

?>
```

See the result [here.](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kak-mmj)